# HTML5 canvas drawImage() function

Tags: html, canvas, drawimage

I am trying to rotating a map.I draw the map on a hidden canvas and after that i am rotating for getting the draw canvas from another canvas.
I implemented first three steps(draw to hidden,rotate,translate) but i could not the last one.Can you help me?
Here is my source code:

```
var visibleCanvas = document.getElementById("VisibleCanvas");
var visibleCtx = visibleCanvas.getContext("2d");
visibleCtx.translate(400,300);
visibleCtx.rotate(Math.PI); 
visibleCtx.drawImage(c,-400,-300,800,600);
```

c is my hidden canvas.I tried a lot of ways to draw the map but i couldn't make it.(like dataURL etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here’s how to draw from one canvas to another with a 180 degree flip**

[image]

```
// save the visibleCtx in it's unrotated state
visibleCtx.save();

// rotate the visible canvas 180 degrees around its centerpoint
visibleCtx.translate(400,300);
visibleCtx.rotate(Math.PI); 
visibleCtx.drawImage(c,-400,-300);

// restore the state of visibleCtx to its unrotated state for future drawings
visibleCtx.restore()
```

Here is code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/2scrB/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; padding:10px;}
    #c{border:3px solid red;}
    #VisibleCanvas{border:3px solid green;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    var c=document.getElementById("c");
    var cCtx=c.getContext("2d");

    var visibleCanvas = document.getElementById("VisibleCanvas");
    var visibleCtx = visibleCanvas.getContext("2d");

    var img=new Image();
    img.onload=function(){

        cCtx.drawImage(img,0,0);

        // note the image being rotated is 400x234
        // so our transformation point is 200x117
        visibleCtx.save()
        visibleCtx.translate(200,117);
        visibleCtx.rotate(Math.PI); 
        visibleCtx.drawImage(c,-200,-117);
        visibleCtx.restore();
    }
    img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/faces.png";


}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <p>Offscreen</p>
    <canvas id="c" width=400 height=234></canvas>
    <p>Visible</p>
    <canvas id="VisibleCanvas" width=400 height=234></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for advice.But it didn't work.I am trying to draw a hidden canvas.So there is no image in my code.Could it be the problem?

Comment: The code is the same (and does work) whether you draw an image or draw a map using context lines/curves/etc.  As noted in my answer...Make sure you context.drawImage(c,-400,-300) -- assuming your offscreen canvas is 800x600.

Comment: I found the problem.I have asynchronous operations to draw on the hiddenCanvas.So i need callback function to rotate that canvas.Thank for all helping.Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to:

1. draw the map on the hidden canvas;
2. rotate the visible canvas; and
3. copy the map from the hidden canvas to the visible canvas?

Assuming your visible canvas has width=800 and height=600 ...

```
var visibleCanvas = document.getElementById("VisibleCanvas");
var visibleCtx = visibleCanvas.getContext("2d");
visibleCtx.translate(400,300);
visibleCtx.rotate(Math.PI);
```

Return the canvas coordinate grid to its original position

```
visibleCtx.translate(-400,-300);
```

The drawImage command has the format:

destinationContext.drawImage(sourceElement, sourceX, sourceY, sourceWidth, sourceHeight, destX, destY, destWidth, destHeight);

... thus "visibleCtx.drawImage(c,-400,-300,800,600);" is telling the canvas to copy the source using coordinates (-400,-300) - which falls outside of the hidden canvas.

Instead, use this:

```
visibleCtx.drawImage(c,0,0,800,600);
```

Because the visible canvas coordinate system origin point has been set back to the top left hand corner, and you don't want to resize the copied image, you don't need to worry about the destination values.

Comment: Yes,you understand exactly the right thing.Thanks for advices.i implemented them into my code but it did not worked again.Do i overlook anything else?